# Ask the user for an input and giving an output based on it, but all gets output from a file that can be updated remotely?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I'm making an app that asks users for their percentage and then give them a list of colleges that they can apply to. There's just one problem, the colleges release four different lists of cut-offs over a span of four weeks, and I want the app to be made in such a way that the I don't have to update a static list inside the app and make the user download the updated version but rather to make the app read that data from a remote location? Is that possible?

Comment: What is your percentage?

Comment: uh the percentage is just something i take from the user as an integer variable to compare with what is essentially a dictionary that contains a college name and percentage.@blackapps